# ardrone_autonomy; rosmake error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
Im am amateur programmer and new to ROS, so please bear with me.
I have been trying to install ardrone_autonomy on ROS electric, Ubuntu 11.10 version running on a virtual machine.
Every time I try the ROSMAKE command I get the following error:

Failed to find rosdep libsdl-dev for package ardrone_autonomy on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
WARNING: Rosdeps [u'libsdl-dev'] could not be resolved
.
.
.
.

### {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir: cannot create directory `build': Permission denied

[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ardrone_autonomy [FAIL] [ 0.23 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package ardrone_autonomy.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 43 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/aalap/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130630-054134
[ rosmake ] WARNING: Rosdep did not detect the following system dependencies as installed: libsdl-dev Consider using --rosdep-install option or `rosdep install ardrone_autonomy`

I tried to install rosdep separately as suggested, tried to independently install libsdl-dev and every other corresponding file. After having referred to a few answers and questions already posted, I also tried to alter certain lines in 'manifest.xml', 'CMakelists.txt' and 'rosdep.yaml' as suggested but to no effect.

Please help.
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66270/ardrone_autonomy;-rosmake-error/) by [Stalwart](https://answers.ros.org/users/5290/stalwart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try installing libsdl-dev using synaptic manager and then install the package.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0